# UTL_HTTP - needs to stop escaping reserved chars

Tags: oracle, plsql

I've got a REST WebService and a PLSQL Package, from which i want to call the WebService. 
The parameters for the call are located within the URI of the WebService.

```
htttp://myservice:8080/some/path/action?value1=123456&value2=some chars&value3=aGermanSonderzeichenCalledÄ
```

As you can see, there are 2 problems with the URI. First the whitespace for value2 and second the special character for value3.

That said, it is clear to me that the URI has to be encoded to a more friendly format. 
The WebService desires UTF-8, so the URI is encoded with: 
`UTL_URL.ESCAPE(url,false,'UTF-8')`.

This results in the following URI:

```
htttp://myservice:8080/some/path/action?value1=123456&value2=some%20chars&value3=aGermanSonderzeichenCalled%C3%84
```

So far, so good. This encoded URI is passed to `UTL_HTTP.BEGIN_REQUEST(url,'GET')`.

When I execute this request, and intercept it with Wireshark, i can see that the actual URI that got called is:

```
htttp://myservice:8080/some/path/action?value1=123456&value2=some%2520chars&value3=aGermanSonderzeichenCalled%25C3%2584
```

What we can see is, that UTL_HTTP escapes the reserved character '%' to %25. 
So in my case the whitespace first got converted to %20 and after that to %2520.

What I'm looking for is a way to stop UTL_HTTP from escaping the reserved characters.
As an alternative, a way in which UTL_HTTP deals with the whitespace and special character, without me calling UTL_URL, would also work for me.

Comment: I would suggest you to add

UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8');
before making the call to utl_http.begin_request

Comment: I already tried adding UTL_HTTP.SET_BODY_CHARSET('UTF-8'), but this doesn't make any difference. The Char '%' in the URL is still replaced by %25

Comment: Facing the same issue here. Does anyone have a solution for that?